# Assign attribute value when saving products

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, product-attribute

A product has an attribute with a list of values A, B, C, ...

When saving the product, I want to compare the first letter of the product names with a list of attribute values. If the attribute value coincided with the first letter of the product, save this value.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Try

Creating an observer for `catalog_product_save_before`

```
<global>
    <events>          
        <catalog_product_save_before>
            <observers> 
                <mymodule>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>mymodule/observer</class>
                    <method>catalog_product_save_before</method>
                </mymodule>
            </observers>
```

In your observer

class MyNamespace_MyModule_Model_Observer
{

```
public function catalog_product_save_before($observer)
{
    $product = $observer->getProduct();

    //check name
    if($product->getName()){
        //then set value
    }
}
```

}